# Book cover with angel with metallic wings

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book. However, I do not remember much unfortunately. Here is what I remember:

- In the center of the cover there was a male person with wings spreading to the sides. The wings looked metallic. The person or statue was seen from the back. I read the book because I was deeply fascinated by the wings.
- The book was in german, but most likely not from a german author (I think).
- I read the book about 15-20 years ago, but the book itself seemed older. Perhaps 1990-2005ish.
- The book was a soft cover book and perhaps 500 pages.
- I do not remember anything about the content. It's genre was science fiction, but it did not play on another planet or in space. It played kind of in the future, but I do not remember anymore what made me think that.
- The book did not contain any angels or aliens.

I'd also be happy with ideas on how to search for books by cover. So far, my Google image searches  were not successful.

Comment: Was the cover painted so the wings looked metallic, or was the cover actually foiled?  Was it flat or embossed?

Comment: @DavidW: It was just a simple paperback. No foil or anything fancy.

Answer (score -1):

“ Iron Angel” by Alan Campbell perhaps? Book jacket is a murky yellow with a metallic humanoid figure on the cover… a cross between a skeleton and a humanoid robot sans skin with wings comprised of slender swordlike feathers.

Comment: Published 2008 according to Google, so not the correct time frame.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The cover doesn't depict a man from the back, and the wings are skeletal and translucent, not really metallic.  It also hasn't been translated into German.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for suggesting an answer. Unfortunately, this is not it.